# Get character from .val() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get some character by index from `.val()` in JQuery?

```
$val = $('#some-id').val(); // $val is '1234'
console.log($val[2]);  // undefined
```

Comment: That looks a bit *impossible*.. your error is somewhere else.

Comment: What browser are you using? If $val is truly '1234' then String.charAt(index) should for sure work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$val = $('#some-id').val(); // This is a string
$val.charAt(2) // Call $val.charAt(index)
```

Comment: If `$val[2]` is undefined, how would `charAt(2)` be defined ?

Comment: That wouldn't work: given that `$val[2]` is `undefined`, then `charAt(2)` will be `undefined` too.

Answer (score 2):

I think method **string.charAt(index)** is what you need.

```
var str = "HELLO WORLD";
console.log(str.charAt(0)); // Display H to console
```